# How can we print the elements of a tuple which contains Arrays?

Tags: arrays, scala, functional-programming, tuples, higher-order-functions

I've applied the partition function on an array, which returns a tuple containing arrays in it.

```
val arrayMap = Array(2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 96)
val parted = arrayMap.partition(_ < 7)
```

How can we print the elements of the resultant tuple 'parted' like this below?

```
Array(2,5,6)
Array(7,8,96)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the elements of the tuple:

```scala
parted._1
// res0: Array[Int] = Array(2, 5, 6)
parted._2
// res1: Array[Int] = Array(7, 8, 96)
```

or, you can use a destructuring bind:

```scala
val (lt7, other) = arrayMap.partition(_ < 7)
// lt7: Array[Int] = Array(2, 5, 6)
// other: Array[Int] = Array(7, 8, 96)
```

Comment: Additionally it is worth mentioning that **Arrays** do not have a pretty `toString` so you need to do this: `println(arr.mkString("Array(", "," , ")"))` - and for that reason, plus invariance, plus mutability; it is better to use other datastructures like **Lists** instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can also directly assign different values of tuples to variables.

```
scala> val (first, second) = arrayMap.partition(_ < 7)
first: Array[Int] = Array(2, 5, 6)
second: Array[Int] = Array(7, 8, 96)
```

Comment: What does this answer provides that the other one didn't had?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Another way of getting tuples in variables instead of using ._1 syntax.